# FragmentPagerAdapter with ViewPager and setCurrentItem - strange behaviour or known bug?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i am having a strange behaviour with a very simple ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter setup.

First of all here is the source code. I have 3 fragments within one adapter. And one callback function for all of the buttons in the corresponding Activity.

Here is Fragment0

```
public class Fragment0 extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment0, container, false);
    }
}
```

and the xml layout for Fragment0

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation=  "vertical"
              android:layout_width= "match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_prev0"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "1"
                android:tag=                "page0"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_next0"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "2"
                android:tag=                "page0"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

with the corresponding layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=            "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation=      "vertical"
              android:layout_width=     "match_parent"
              android:layout_height=    "match_parent">

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_prev1"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "2"
                android:tag=                "page1"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_next1"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "0"
                android:tag=                "page1"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment2:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }
}
```

and also here the simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation=  "horizontal"
              android:layout_width= "match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_prev2"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "0"
                android:tag=                "page2"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>

    <Button     android:id=                 "@+id/pager_button_next2"
                android:layout_width=       "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height=      "wrap_content"
                android:text=               "1"
                android:tag=                "page2"
                android:onClick=            "pagerTestClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Okay, quite straightforward right? Here is the FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class Fragment_Pager_Adapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
{
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

/**
 * default constructor
 */
public Fragment_Pager_Adapter(FragmentManager fm)
{
    super(fm);
    Fragment0 fragment0 =  new Fragment0();
    this.fragments.add(fragment0);
    Fragment1 fragment1 =  new Fragment1();
    this.fragments.add(fragment1);
    Fragment2 fragment2 =  new Fragment2();
    this.fragments.add(fragment2);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    if (position >= this.getCount())
    {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Also no voodoo here. And slowly we are coming to the problem. As you see in the XML layout files, i am calling "pagerTestClick" in for each button. This is the function:

```
public void pagerTestClick(View view)
{
    int page = Integer.parseInt(((Button) view).getText().toString());
    String tag = view.getTag().toString();
    this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
}
```

**So now the PROBLEM**

When I am clicking through the 3 pages. First clicks everything seems fine. But at a certain point, something gets messed up. Even though I am on page1 and clicking the button "0" to get to page0, the function "pagerTestClick" seems to be called for the button on the page2 because the "tag" string is "page2".

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a known bug?

**ADDITIONAL PROBLEM**

If i am swiping through the pages with a swipe, everthings works fine on all pages (for example if i add some additional buttons on each page) But when i am using "setCurrentItem" and selecting the page manually, it seems that the clickable area is not the full size of the page. That means, if i add some extra ui buttons to the pages, just some of them are clickable. 
If I do swipe transition to page0 and then with swipe to pageX, then everything works fine.

**Is the whole problem maybe related to "setCurrentItem"? Do I have to call anything special after I call "setCurrentItem"?

**even stranger behaviour**

I have found out an even stranger behaviour. When I click through the pages via "setCurrentItem", then at some point it seems that I can click "through" the current page and click the buttons on the page that was shown before. Thats means, when i am on page2, and clicking to page1 with "setCurrentItem" then it seems that I still can click the elements of page2 (for this case I have added some widely spread dummy buttons on each page)

Comment: The best way is to have a callback interface in each Fragment and let your Activity implement them. If you are doing this for learning, then, I would also like to learn.

Comment: well... i will try that.. here is a good google example (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), but i guess thats an overkill for my purpose. I will try it and give some feedback

Comment: well, same behaviour with callback interfaces. I have updated my question because i found some even more strange behaviours, but i guess they are all realated to the "setCurrentItem" function

Comment: well, i have created a bug.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82002&thanks=82002&ts=1418031003